# Can't submit a file in an Ajax Form in MVC4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to upload a file to my server using the ajax form of MVC4.

Here's my form "head":

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "repoFiles"
    },
    new
    {
        enctype = "multipart/form-data"
    }))
{
    // file input here
}
```

Debugging in Visual Studio 2012 I can't recover the file in the request, but if I change the form to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home",
```

I can get the file normally. Why this happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. If you want to use asynchronous uploads then you can use something like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)